# regex validation

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to validate a string of 3 numbers followed by / then 5 more numbers
I thought this would work

```
(/^([0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+/[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9])/i)
```

but it doesn't, any ideas what i'm doing wrong

Comment: What do you think the `+` characters are doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're using `/` as the regexp delimiter, so you can't use it in the pattern without escaping it with a backslash. Otherwise, PHP will think that you're pattern ends at the `/` in the middle (you can see that even StackOverflow's syntax highlighting thinks so).

Second, the `+` is "greedy", and will match as many characters as it can, so the first `[0-9]+` would match the first 3 numbers in one go, leaving nothing for the next two to match.

Third, there's no need to use `i`, since you're dealing with numbers which aren't upper- or lowercase, so case-sensitivity is a moot point.

Try this instead

```
/^\d{3}\/\d{5}$/
```

The `\d` is  shorthand for writing `[0-9]`, and the `{3}` and `{5}` means repeat 3 or 5 times, respectively.

(This pattern is anchored to the start and the end of the string. Your pattern was only anchored to the beginning, and if that was on purpose, the remove the `$` from my pattern)

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
preg_match('@^\d{3}/\d{5}@', $string)
```

The reason yours is not working is due to the `+` symbols which match "one or more" of the nominated character or character class.

Also, when using forward-slash delimiters (the characters at the start and end of your expression), you need to escape any forward-slashes in the pattern by prefixing them with a backslash, eg

```
/foo\/bar/
```

PHP allows you to use alternate delimiters (as in my answer) which is handy if your expression contains many forward-slashes.

Answer (score 1):

I recently found this site useful for debugging regexes:
  http://www.regextester.com/index2.html

It assumes use of `/.../`  (meaning you should not include those slashes in the regex you paste in).

So, after I put your regex `^([0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+/[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9])` in the Regex box and `123/45678` in the Test box I see no match. When I put a backslash in front of the forward slash in the middle, then it recognizes the match. You can then try matching `1234/567890` and discover it still matches. Then you go through and remove all the plus signs and then it correctly stops matching.

What I particularly like about this particular site is the way it shows the partial matches in red, allowing you to see where your regex is working up to.